# Floating Button Start New Activity

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have a problem with starting new activity via Floating Button. When I add next code into my `onCreate` method, app will crash down after start.

```
FloatingActionButton addEvent = (FloatingActionButton) this.findViewById(R.id.float_btn_add_event);
addEvent.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        startActivity(new Intent(IndexActivity.this, AddEventActivity.class));
    }
});
```

Here is my Floating Button.

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/float_btn_add_event"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
    android:src="@mipmap/ic_add"
    app:layout_anchor="@id/listView1"
    app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end"
    android:layout_marginRight="13dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="12dp"
    app:backgroundTint="#ffffff"
    android:layout_marginEnd="13dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:onClick="addEvent" />
```

I tried second solution. I created next activity, but the result is the same.

```
public void addEvent(View view) {
    startActivity(new Intent(this, AddEventActivity.class));
}
```

Be patient please, I am a beginner. :)

Comment: please post the stacktrace of the error

Comment: Here you have a link. https://codeshare.io/MyError1
Too long for post it here. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove this import from your project `com.melnykov.fab.FloatingActionButton` and import this `android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton`.

Also double check that you have register your `AddEventActivity` in manifest.

Comment: Happy Coding. Try to add activities from File > New > Activity in android studio. Wizard will automatically register activity in manifest. :)

Comment: Thank you for your advice! :)

Answer (score 0):

Remove import of your FloatingActionButton in your Java class and reimport exactly

```
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
```

Comment: It still does the same thing.
I tried 
`import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;`
and too
`import com.melnykov.fab.FloatingActionButton;`

Comment: I have mentioned in my answer that double check your manifest file for AddEventActivity registration.